# Set value based on Checkbox being True or False using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to display a value of "Yes" or "No" depending on if a checkbox is checked.  If checked, I want to display "Yes" if not, display "No".

I have tried a few variants of the following code, but have not been able to get it to work. set

%%[var @rs2
Set @rs2= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Reservation__c', 'SPF14_Purchased__c','Household__c','=', @ID)

set @row=row(@rs2,1)
set @SPF14=field(@row,'SPF14_Purchased__c')

%%[IF  (@SPF14 == True) THEN ]%%
%%[ SET @SPF14 = Yes' ]%%

%%[ELSEIF (@SPF14 == False) THEN]%%
%%[SET @SPF14 = 'No']%%
%%[ELSE]%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
ENDIF
]%%

Comment: Try `true` and `false` instead of `"true”` and `"false”`. It’s hard to troubleshoot the rest of your script, as it seems incomplete

Comment: I tried true and false and that did not work.  I added the rest of the script in my original question.  Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: You have a variable `@ID` which is not set. And you could put all that script in one block, but that’s not the issue here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 endif however only one if is set. You should delete the additional endif in the end. Also your code is all ampscript and therefore 1 ampscript block should be used. Also ' was missing before the yes value. As zuzannamj metioned the @ID parameter is not defined. You should set it before using it to reterive the object from SF.

See fixed code below:

```
%%[

set @ID='Value should be inserted here' 
set @rs2= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Reservation__c', 
'SPF14_Purchased__c','Household__c','=', @ID)
set @row=row(@rs2,1) 
set @SPF14=field(@row,'SPF14_Purchased__c')

IF (@SPF14 == 'True' ) THEN 

SET @SPF14 = 'Yes' 
ELSEIF (@SPF14 == 'False' ) THEN 
SET @SPF14 = 'No' 

ENDIF

]%%
```

Comment: Thank you Barak.  Your recommendations were great.  I did have to use double quotes ("yes" and "No") to get them to display.  Thank you!